# When the locator in the cluster loses network connectivity, the client attempts to connect to other locator , but the connection is refused

Tags: gemfire, geode

I have encountered some issues while building applications against Apache Geode or deploying Apache Geode. I would appreciate it if you could take some time to assist me with these problems.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkHd.png)
I am trying to set up the topology and communication as described above.  I believe my deployment and configuration are correct, because when the network connection is normal, two clients can connect and access the locator normally. However, when the server where the locator at 192.168.11.140 is disconnected from the network, the client at 192.168.11.192 cannot access the locator on the same server at 192.168.11.192, reporting the following error. Is this error expected, or do I need to modify my configuration?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klmGu.png)
Here are my configurations for the two servers:

1.Server with IP address 192.168.11.140:

> start locator --name=locator90 --bind-address=192.168.11.140 --port=10334 --mcast-port=0 --locators='192.168.11.192[10334]' --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager=true --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-start=true

> connect --locator=192.168.11.140[10334]
> start server --name=server90 --locators='192.168.11.140[10334],192.168.11.192[10334]' --server-port=40404 --bind-address=192.168.11.140  --classpath=../build/classes
> start server --name=server902 --locators='192.168.11.140[10334]' --server-port=40405 --bind-address=192.168.11.140  --classpath=../build/classes
> create region --name=DeviceOnlineRegion --type=REPLICATE
> 2.Server with IP address 192.168.11.192:

> start locator --name=locator91 --bind-address=192.168.11.192 --port=10334 --mcast-port=0 --locators=192.168.11.140[10334]  --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager=true --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-start=true

> connect --locator=192.168.11.192[10334]
> start server --name=server91 --locators=192.168.11.140[10334],192.168.11.192[10334] --server-port=40404 --bind-address=192.168.11.192  --classpath=../build/classes
> start server --name=server912 --locators=192.168.11.192[10334] --server-port=40405 --bind-address=192.168.11.192  --classpath=../build/classes

3.Both servers have started a client process, and the client code connects to the locator as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MeetCCSControlApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MeetCCSControlApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ClientCacheConfigurer clientCachePoolPortConfigurer(
            @Value("${gemfire.cache.locator.host:localhost}") String cacheServerHost,
          @Value("${gemfire.cache.locator.port:10334}") int cacheServerPort) {

        return (beanName, clientCacheFactoryBean) ->{
            clientCacheFactoryBean.setLocators(Collections.singletonList(
                    new ConnectionEndpoint("192.168.11.192", 10334)));
            clientCacheFactoryBean.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
        };
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and assistance. I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Thank you for your time and assistance. I look forward to hearing from you soon.